# Angular define own directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently trying to define my own directive in Angular, which doesn't to more then a `console.log()`. What I tried was the following:

log.directive.js:

```
export default function () {
    return {
        bindToController: {
            val: '=log-dir'
        },
        controllerAs: '$ctrl',
        template: "",
        controller: function () {
            console.log("test");
        }
    };
}
```

Then I import the directive:

```
import logDirDirective from '../../directives/log.directive';
```

and add it to my module:

```
angular.module(MODULE_NAME).directive('log-dir',logDirDirective);
```

And then, in my HTML I try to use it as:

```
<div class="......" log-dir>
</div>
```

What I expected now, is to see `test` in my console after loading, but I don't. Where is the mistake?

PS: Please note that I'm relatively new to angular and completely new to selfmade directives, so my mistake might me very trivial.

Comment: Refer https://github.com/comsysto/angular-architecture/tree/master/deckmanager/components for components which are needed in building a directive...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directive names and binding/scope config must conform to normalization conventions. It means that correct definition of the directive should be:

```
angular.module(MODULE_NAME).directive('logDir', logDirDirective);
```

And the same for bindings config:

```
bindToController: {
    val: '=logDir'
},
```

Check ["AngularJs directive naming conventions"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33460274/angularjs-directive-naming-conventions/33460305#33460305) question for more detailed answer to why.

**UPD.**

Here is a demo of variations with @ and = bindings: http://plnkr.co/edit/mA0YnVhd7t241kdAvgRl?p=info

Comment: This doesn't seem to change anything, I wonder why angulars directives would work then (like `ng-click`, etc..)

Comment: hold on, my bad... I also changed (intuitively) it in the html, but then realized, that there, everything has to stay the same (so log-dir). Now it works. Can you tell me, what I'd have to change to log a string, specified when I write the directive in HTML, so I can write `div log-dir="special string"`and then in console I can find that string?

Comment: According to your `bindToController` config, it binds attribute `log-dir` to controller property named `val`. So it means, you will be able to do `console.log(this.val)`. But also note, that `=` means two-way data binding, i.e. it needs to be a valid Angular statement. If you want attribute to be just a string you should use directive like this `log-dir="'special string'"`.

Comment: Hmm, somehow I'm getting `undefined` as value. I'm right, just changing `console.log("test")` to `console.log(this.val)` and then writing `<div log-dir="another test"></div>` right?

Comment: Got it, didn't have the single quotes for the string in my directive, thank you.

Comment: No, read my previous comment. If you write `val: '=logDir'` then you need to use `<div log-dir="'another test'"></div>` (not quotes inside `"`). The string must be valid expression. However if it was `val: '@logDir'` then you could write `<div log-dir="another test"></div>`. Let me know if something is still unclear, it can be tricky at first.

Comment: Could I still pass something else then a string when I would use `@logDir`? If yes, whats better using `=` or is `@` always better?

Comment: Depending on what you want from your directive. Let me make a demo with couple of examples.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116806/discussion-between-user5638730-and-dfsq).

Comment: Okay, forget the chat, I got it, thanks for your help.