# Angular conditional templateURL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to use conditional *templateURL* through attribute in my directive. here is my code :

**MapMarker.js :**

```
app.directive('mapMarker',function(){
    return {
'app/user/ngApp/templates/libsView/templates/directives/map.html',
        templateUrl : function (elem , attrs) {
            if (attrs["mapRequire"] == "yes")
            {
                console.info("have yes");
            }
            else
            {

                console.info("doesn't have yes" , attrs["mapRequire"]);
            }
          return attrs["mapRequire"] == "yes" ?
                        'this is text' : '../templates/directives/map1.html';
        },
```

**HTML :**

```
<map-marker mapRequire = "yes"></map-marker>
```

It return  `doesn't have yes undefined` .

Why? Any suggestion for dynamic template url depends on attribute?
But the way , Is it the best way?

Comment: This is related question about directive/attribute naming conventions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33460274/angularjs-directive-naming-conventions/33460305#33460305

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember about standard [normalization conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33460274/angularjs-directive-naming-conventions/33460305#33460305). kebab-case in HTML translates to camelCase in JS.

It should looks like this:

```
<map-marker map-require="yes"></map-marker>
```

Answer (score 1):

All html attributes have to be in snake case(only small letter and '-' is allowed)..

and you are using the mapRequire attribute in camel case form

Instead you should use it as

```
<map-marker map-require = "yes"></map-marker>
```

Answer (score -1):

try 
choose-directive

instead of conditional url.